# Shrink some blocks of ciphertext in AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I need to decrypt an AES ciphertext, for which I have the key. The problem is that on decryption in Java, an error occurs:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

I suppose it was a problem on data persisting in the database and that some part of the the data is corrupt (because there was no problems so far, it can't be the key). The length of the ciphertext is a multiple of 16.

Two questions:

1. If I would I delete the last 16-byte block, would it be possible to decrypt the data?
2. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Bad padding could be lots of things, including using the wrong key, IV, or padding specification during decryption. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue would help us determine what is wrong in your process.

Comment: @Dev thanks. I will try to debug deeper and will come eventually with some updates. Any ideas related to the first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit padding using `NOPADDING` for padding spec when encrypting if you can guarantee that your message length will always be a multiple of the AES block size which is 16 bytes. You can also omit padding if you use AES in a mode that doesn't require padding (i.e. `CTR` mode).

Also, you can always attempt to decrypt a padded message with `NOPADDING` but you'll have to deal with the padding in the plaintext at some point.

Overall you're probably better off trying to figure out why your message is not decrypting properly instead of trying workarounds. Workarounds when dealing with crypto are generally not a good idea.

Comment: I was using `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` which seems to be the same with "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". When switched to "AES/ECB/NoPadding" I succeeded to decrypt the ciphertext, which seems to be only a part of original plaintext. Pretty big chances are, that the problem comes from using the same instance of cipher in multiple threads. Thanks for the suggestion, Dev.

Comment: @AndreiI Glad I could help. Just note that `ECB` mode is insecure if you are encrypting more than 16-bytes (1 block) with the same key, so if your using this cipher configuration for a real security purpose I recommend you revisit your implementation.

Comment: thanks for tip, initially I thought it was another default mode. I will see for a solution, in order to remain compatible with the existing data.